# Error splitting value into substring fields

Tags: typescript, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to typescript and I am trying to extract data from fields in DynamoDB using typescript. I need to be able to split a string field into 2 substrings and store in 2 separate variables.

Sample Data:

```
Id    days  end             createdAt   type
123   3     2021-07-22#AM   21/10/2020  Leave#Upskilling
342   7     2021-10-22#PM   15/02/2021  Long Term Leave#Parental
```

Expected Output Data:

```
Id    days    end              createdAt     type                  subleavetype
123   3       2021-07-22#AM    21/10/2020    Leave                 Upskilling
342   7       2021-10-22#PM    15/02/2021    Long Term Leave       Parental
```

This is what I have done so far:

```
   recordsToJoin.push(
    getAttributeValue(newImage.id),
    getAttributeValue(newImage.days), 
    getAttributeValue(newImage.end),
    getAttributeValue(newImage.createdAt, true),
    getAttributeValue(newImage.type.split('#')[0])),
    getAttributeValue(newImage.type.split('#')[1]), 
  );
```

However, I am getting errors so please help.

This is the code file we are calling for the getAtrributevalue..

```
import { AttributeValue } from 'aws-sdk/clients/dynamodb';
import { decodeTimestamp } from '../dates/dates';

export const getAttributeValue = (
  attribute: AttributeValue,
  isDate = false,
): string => {
  if (attribute == null) {
    return '';
  }
  const keys = Object.keys(attribute);
  if (isDate) {
    if (keys[0] == 'N') {
      return decodeTimestamp(Number(attribute.N));
    } else {
      return '';
    }
  } else if (keys[0] == 'S') {
    return attribute.S;
  } else if (keys[0] == 'N') {
    return attribute.N;
  } else if (keys[0] == 'NULL') {
    return '';
  } else if (keys[0] == 'BOOL') {
    return attribute.BOOL.toString();
  } else {
    //else if statement can be extended to add more types
    return '';
  }
};

export const getCommaSeparatedValues = (
  attributeList: AttributeValue[],
): string => {
  const attributes: string[] = [];
  for (const attribute of attributeList) {
    attributes.push(attribute.S);
  }
  return attributes.join(',');
};
```

The error message is: Property 'split' does not exist on type 'AttributeValue'.

Comment: What error are you getting? You need to provide more info

Comment: Property 'split' does not exist on type 'AttributeValue'.ts(2339)
any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is throwing because your are splitting before to get the value

```
recordsToJoin.push(
   getAttributeValue(newImage.id),
   getAttributeValue(newImage.days), 
   getAttributeValue(newImage.end),
   getAttributeValue(newImage.createdAt, true),
   getAttributeValue(newImage.type).split('#')[0],
   getAttributeValue(newImage.type).split('#')[1], 
);
```